# Symfony2 enable debugger by user or role

Tags: php, symfony

I want to enable the debugger on a Sf2 project depending on user, or role, and I can't find any way to do this.
Does anybody know how can I override the $debug variable on the environment app file in order to let only some users see the symfony error pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about overriding a configuration value, it's about configuring the profiler so that it only pops up when a rule matches.

This could be implemented with a [profiler matcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/matchers.html). Take a look at the documentation, it describes how to enable profiler for those users who have a given role. In your case you could rewrite the examples a bit and implement any user checks you could wish for.